# How add Mask to InputTags in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tags, mask

I have `input-tag` in my view, but I want set mask for each tag : `digit-digit`
like: 1-3, 44-56

How can I set that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

first all two libraries in head

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

then below will be your `textbox`

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number,  new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" } )
```

here `x.Number` will be the property
and your script will be

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#phone").mask("99-99");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but your help is for textbox....I want set mask for each tag in taginput